# Extreme points in the intersection of hyperplanes and hypercube

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let $A$ be any $c \times n$ matrix such that $c < n$ and let $b$ be any $c\times 1$ vector. It is also known that $A$ and $b$ are element-wise positive. Consider the set defined as 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}=\{x~|~Ax\leq b~,~x\in[0,1]^n\}
\end{align}
where $[0,1]^n$ is the standard hypercube. If $\mathcal{S}$ is non-empty with at least two points, it is easy to see that $\mathcal{S}$ is a closed convex set. I am interested in the extreme points of $\mathcal{S}$. Extreme points are the points which can never be contained inside a non-degenerate line in $\mathcal{S}$ (can be thought of as corners). Another way to say is, they can never be written as convex-combinations of two other points in $\mathcal{S}$. Is the following statement true?

*Question: if $e$ is an extreme point of $\mathcal{S}$, the number of components in vector $e$ such that $0<e_i<1$ is upper-bounded by $c$.*

Comment: I don't understand the presence of the adjective "fractional" in "the number of fractional terms" ; what you are looking for is "the number of components ... such that $0<e_i<1$". Maybe you were thinking that these components belong to $\mathbb{Q}$, but this is the case only if the entries of $A$ themselves belong to $\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: @JeanMarie corrected that, from a engineering background :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand now the meaning you give to "decimals" (numbers less than 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertices are basic feasible solutions, hence the claim is true.

A basic feasible solution satisfies $n$ linearly independent active constraint.

Let $M$ corresponds to the indices of the linearly independent inequalities that are active from $Ax \le b$.
Let $x$ be a basic solution and $x_{B(1)}, \ldots x_{B(k)}$ that satisfies $0<x_{B(i)}<1$. Let $J$ denotes the indices that attains $x_i=1$, then we reduces the problem to

$$\sum_{j =1}^Ka_{iB(j)}x_{B(j)} =b_i-\sum_{j \in J}a_{ij}, \forall i \in M$$

and we know that it has a unique solution. The columns corresponding to $B(k)$ must be linearly independent.  Hence $K \le c$.

Comment: how can there be $n$ linearly independent active constraints?, did you mean $c$?

Comment: the size of $x$ is $n$, the other linearly independent active constraints comes from the box constraints.